# Looping through an array to populate the variables for nivoSlider with each slide having its own settings

Tags: php, jquery, nivo-slider

This is my third attempt at asking this question differently regarding the population of nivoSlider setting with data returned by a query. Here I have tried to provide a better explanation of what I am trying to do.

This is what I am trying to do. I have two records in the table which contain the image name, effect, slices, boxCols, boxRows, animSpeed and pauseTime.

Run the script which returns the data and displays the images for each record using nivoSlider. Each slide has different display requirement, example:

Slide No1:
effect - sliceUp
slices - 30
boxCols - 16
boxRows - 8
animSpeed - 8000
pauseTime - 12000

Slide No2:
effect - boxRain
slices - 10
boxCols - 12
boxRows - 8
animSpeed - 8000
pauseTime - 6000

The nivoSlider script looks like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: '<?php echo $row['Effect'];?>',
    slices:  '<?php echo $rowe['Slices'];?>',
    boxCols:'<?php echo $row['Cols'];?>',
    boxRows:  '<?php echo $row['Rows'];?>',
    animSpeed:'<?php echo $row['AnimSpeed'];?>',
    pauseTime: '<?php echo $row['TimeLapse'];?>',
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
    controlNavThumbs: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    manualAdvance: false,
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){},
    lastSlide: function(){},
    afterLoad: function(){}
  });
});
```

I then have a PHP loop to display each image one after the other:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
   <?php while($row_Signage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: '<?php echo $row['Effect'];?>',
        slices:  '<?php echo $row['Slices'];?>',
        boxCols:'<?php echo $row['Cols'];?>',
        boxRows:  '<?php echo $row['Rows'];?>',
        animSpeed:'<?php echo $row['AnimSpeed'];?>',
        pauseTime: '<?php echo $row['TimeLapse'];?>',
        startSlide: 0,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: false,
        controlNavThumbs: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        manualAdvance: false,
        randomStart: false,
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){},
        lastSlide: function(){},
        afterLoad: function(){}
      });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
      echo '<img src="/'.$ImagePath .''.$row['PromotionImage'].'"/> ';
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the nivoSlider script inside of the while loop I expected the code to get the first record and display it using the variable in the nivoSlider script. It does display the images but it also displays a blank page with the error:

> example.com/apps/signage/EXBHX/DS2/undefined.

It has been suggested that I need to move a part of the code outside of the while loop, so I tried this:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $effect = $row['Effect'];
  $slices = $row['Slices'];
  $boxCols = $row['Cols'];
  $boxRows = $row['Rows'];
  $animSpeed = $row['AnimSpeed'];
  $pauseTime = $row['TimeLapse'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: '<?php echo $effect;?>',
    slices:  '<?php echo $slices;?>',
    boxCols:'<?php echo $boxCols;?>',
    boxRows:  '<?php echo $boxRows;?>',
    animSpeed:'<?php echo $animSpeed ;?>',
    pauseTime: '<?php echo $pauseTime;?>',
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
    controlNavThumbs: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    manualAdvance: false,
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){},
    lastSlide: function(){},
    afterLoad: function(){}
  });
});
</script>
<?php
  echo '<img src="/'.$ImagePath .''.$row['PromotionImage'].'"/> ';
?>
<?php } ?>
```

The above produces the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect: 'sliceUp',
slices:  '30',
boxCols:'16',
boxRows:  '8',
animSpeed:'8000',
pauseTime: '12000',
startSlide: 0,
directionNav: false,
controlNav: false,
controlNavThumbs: false,
pauseOnHover: false,
manualAdvance: false,
randomStart: false,
beforeChange: function(){},
afterChange: function(){},
slideshowEnd: function(){},
lastSlide: function(){},
afterLoad: function(){}
});
});
</script>
<img src="/apps/signage/promotion_images/EXBHX/boards/DS2/monday_portrait.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect: 'boxRain',
slices:  '10',
boxCols:'12',
boxRows:  '8',
animSpeed:'8000',
pauseTime: '6000',
startSlide: 0,
directionNav: false,
controlNav: false,
controlNavThumbs: false,
pauseOnHover: false,
manualAdvance: false,
randomStart: false,
beforeChange: function(){},
afterChange: function(){},
slideshowEnd: function(){},
lastSlide: function(){},
afterLoad: function(){}
});
});
</script>
<img src="/apps/signage/promotion_images/EXBHX/boards/DS2/tuesday_portrait.png"/>
```

This does not work, it displays the same:

> error: example.com/apps/signage/EXBHX/DS2/undefined

This does not stop the script from running but it does display a blank page at the start of the display loop.

I could write more on the different ways I have ordered the code but nothing works.

Code from the library:

```
Line 90 to line 111

    //Create caption
    slider.append($('<div class="nivo-caption"></div>'));
    
    // Process caption function
    var processCaption = function(settings){
        var nivoCaption = $('.nivo-caption', slider);
        if(vars.currentImage.attr('title') != '' && vars.currentImage.attr('title') != undefined){
            var title = vars.currentImage.attr('title');
            if(title.substr(0,1) == '#') title = $(title).html();   

            if(nivoCaption.css('display') == 'block'){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    nivoCaption.html(title);
                }, settings.animSpeed);
            } else {
                nivoCaption.html(title);
                nivoCaption.stop().fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
            }
        } else {
            nivoCaption.stop().fadeOut(settings.animSpeed);
        }
    }
    

Line 210 to line 240

    // Add slices for slice animations
    var createSlices = function(slider, settings, vars) {
        if($(vars.currentImage).parent().is('a')) $(vars.currentImage).parent().css('display','block');
        $('img[src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'"]', slider).not('.nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img').width(slider.width()).css('visibility', 'hidden').show();
        var sliceHeight = ($('img[src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'"]', slider).not('.nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img').parent().is('a')) ? $('img[src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'"]', slider).not('.nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img').parent().height() : $('img[src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'"]', slider).not('.nivo-main-image,.nivo-control img').height();

        for(var i = 0; i < settings.slices; i++){
            var sliceWidth = Math.round(slider.width()/settings.slices);
            
            if(i === settings.slices-1){
                slider.append(
                    $('<div class="nivo-slice" name="'+i+'"><img src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:auto; display:block !important; top:0; left:-'+ ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
                        left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px', 
                        width:(slider.width()-(sliceWidth*i))+'px',
                        height:sliceHeight+'px', 
                        opacity:'0',
                        overflow:'hidden'
                    })
                );
            } else {
                slider.append(
                    $('<div class="nivo-slice" name="'+i+'"><img src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:auto; display:block !important; top:0; left:-'+ ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
                        left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px', 
                        width:sliceWidth+'px',
                        height:sliceHeight+'px',
                        opacity:'0',
                        overflow:'hidden'
                    })
                );
            }
        }
```

Line 256 to line 286

```
        for(var rows = 0; rows < settings.boxRows; rows++){
            for(var cols = 0; cols < settings.boxCols; cols++){
                if(cols === settings.boxCols-1){
                    slider.append(
                        $('<div class="nivo-box" name="'+ cols +'" rel="'+ rows +'"><img src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:auto; display:block; top:-'+ (boxHeight*rows) +'px; left:-'+ (boxWidth*cols) +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
                            opacity:0,
                            left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px', 
                            top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',
                            width:(slider.width()-(boxWidth*cols))+'px'
                            
                        })
                    );
                    $('.nivo-box[name="'+ cols +'"]', slider).height($('.nivo-box[name="'+ cols +'"] img', slider).height()+'px');
                } else {
                    slider.append(
                        $('<div class="nivo-box" name="'+ cols +'" rel="'+ rows +'"><img src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:auto; display:block; top:-'+ (boxHeight*rows) +'px; left:-'+ (boxWidth*cols) +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
                            opacity:0,
                            left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px', 
                            top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',
                            width:boxWidth+'px'
                        })
                    );
                    $('.nivo-box[name="'+ cols +'"]', slider).height($('.nivo-box[name="'+ cols +'"] img', slider).height()+'px');
                }
            }
        }
        
        sliderImg.stop().animate({
            height: $(vars.currentImage).height()
        }, settings.animSpeed);
    };

Line 356 to line 364

        // Run random effect from specified set (eg: effect:'fold,fade')
        if(settings.effect.indexOf(',') !== -1){
            anims = settings.effect.split(',');
            currentEffect = anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length))];
            if(currentEffect === undefined) { currentEffect = 'fade'; }
        }
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly hi and thanks for your reply but not very helpful while I am trying to solve my question. This issue is with the placement of the code not using mysql as apposed to mysqli.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi there, I have now change the query to mysqli. I still have the same issues, can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used nivoslider before. Also, I can't find any detailed doc for this plugin. So, I have decided to take a look at its code.

As I understood this plugin used common config (option) object for all of the images inside the slider.

I can't find a way to change the attributes for each image by default.

So, I have decided to edit the library code.

My goal is simple. Instead of taking the slider attributes from the option, I want to pass those attributes inside `img` tag like `data-nseffect='boxRain'`. then in the library, I want to access it like `.data('nseffect')`.

**Here the changes I have made in the library.**

> Line Number: 361

```
  var currentEffect = vars.currentImage.data('nseffect') || settings.effect;
  console.log('effect', currentEffect);
```

> Line Number: 223

```
  settings.slices = vars.currentImage.data('nsslices') || settings.slices;
  console.log('slices', settings.slices);
```

> Line Number: 263

```
  settings.boxCols = vars.currentImage.data('nsboxcols') || settings.boxCols;
  console.log('boxCols', settings.boxCols);

  settings.boxRows = vars.currentImage.data('nsboxrows') || settings.boxRows;
  console.log('boxRows', settings.boxRows);
```

> Line Number: 99

```
  settings.animSpeed = vars.currentImage.data('nsanimspeed') || settings.animSpeed;
  console.log('animSpeed', settings.animSpeed);
```

Unfortunately, It takes `pauseTime` only from the 1st `img` attribute and creates a `setInterval` So, It should be common to all of the images inside the slider.

**Here the HTML part.**

```
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/toystory.jpg"
        data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg"
        alt = ""
        data-nseffect = "boxRain"
        data-nsslices = "30"
        data-nsboxcols = "10"
        data-nsboxrows = "5"
        data-nsanimspeed = "5000"
        data-nspausetime = "3000"
        />

        <a href="http://dev7studios.com">
          <img src="images/up.jpg"
          title="This is an example of a caption"
          data-nseffect = "sliceUp"
          data-nsslices = "35"
          data-nsboxcols = "15"
          data-nsboxrows = "6"
          data-nsanimspeed = "3000"
          data-nspausetime = "3000"
           />
        </a>

      ...
      ...

    </div>
```

**Finally in PHP**

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $effect = $row['Effect'];
 $slices = $row['Slices'];
 $boxCols = $row['Cols'];
 $boxRows = $row['Rows'];
 $animSpeed = $row['AnimSpeed'];
 $pauseTime = $row['TimeLapse'];
 echo '<img src="/'.$ImagePath .''.$row['PromotionImage'].'"
    data-nseffect = "'.$effect.'"
    data-nsslices = "'.$slices.'"
    data-nsboxcols = "'.$boxCols.'"
    data-nsboxrows = "'.$boxRows.'"
    data-nsanimspeed = "'.$animSpeed.'"
    data-nspausetime = "'.$pauseTime.'"
    />';
  }?>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

**Note:** I took this library from their official GitHub [here](https://github.com/Codeinwp/Nivo-Slider-jQuery/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.js).

It works for me. Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your reply, this is very interesting. When you say you made changes to the library, were they changes or did you add new code?

Comment: I mentioned in the answer. Including the line number.  and I took the lib from here https://github.com/Codeinwp/Nivo-Slider-jQuery/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.js (here where I made the changes)

Comment: hi again. After downloading the library I am struggling matching line numbers with the code you gave me. Is it possible to email me the library you have. If so my email address is dereck.jones@gmail.com

Comment: Hi again, I have added the relative parts from the library, Could you point out where I should be putting your code changes. Many thanks again for all your time.

Comment: Here the fiddle. https://codesandbox.io/s/wy3k5kwm0w 
But, it's not working there, Download and run it your local machine it will work. @DCJones

Comment: Hi, outstanding. working perfectly. Again, many thanks for all your time,

Comment: you are welcome. :) you can support me by upvoting my correct answers. @DCJones

Comment: @ Prabu samvel I most certainly will.